# How to refresh/reload CSS style in loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function which should to change `<div>` left position in loop making it to look like it is moving. But instead it just jumps to the end position.

```
function anim (id, left) {
    $('#k' + id).css('left', parseInt($('#k' + id).css('left')) + 1);
    if(parseInt($('#k' + id).css('left')) == left){
        return;
    }
   setTimeout(anim(id, left), 100);
}
```

I want it to look like jQuery animate but without using jQuery animate function. **What I miss?**

EDIT
working example: http://jsfiddle.net/h7MuB/21/

Comment: That syntax `anim function (id, left) {` is all wrong.. It guess you meant `function anim(id, left) {` instead..

Comment: @techfoobar you are right, my mistake. I was editing my original code to make it more simple and easier to understand. After your suggestion I edited my example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've misunderstood the argument to `setTimeout`.

```
setTimeout(anim(id, left), 100);
```

should be

```
setTimeout(function() { anim(id, left); }, 100);
```

This is a common mistake.  You want to pass a *function* to `setTimeout`.  What you were doing is *calling* the function, and passing its *return value* (which, since you don't have a `return` statement, is `undefined`).

That's why the animation "jumped": because you were calling the next step immediately, and not really using the timeout.

Note that you *can* use a function name with no `function () {}` wrapper, if you do not need to pass arguments.  If you want to pass arguments, you need to create a closure as above.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess it's probably doing what you want it to do, but it's working too fast for it to actually appear animated, you should try delaying your script in each iteration to get a visual animation. Check out this function... [SetTimeOut()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

Comment: setTimeout is not changing anything except that i have to wait longer to see div jump

Comment: looks like harpo set you straight on that one, glad you got it worked out.